# Angular Directive to block value changes conditionally

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application I am subscribed to value change in a specific form field, and I want to avoid that value changes to be invoked if the input is < 3 character, this is the value change:

```
this.posForm.controls["customer"].valueChanges
  .pipe(
    tap(() => (this.load = true)),
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap(val => this.customerService.getCustomers(this.basicService.handleValueAutocomplete(val, "lastName"))),
    tap(() => (this.load = false))
  )
  .subscribe(customers => {
    this.matchingCustomers.next(customers);
  });
```

So I tried with a directive but the value changes is always triggered:

```
@Directive({

selector: "[blockValueChangesDirective]"
})
export class BlockValueChangesDirective {
  inputElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.inputElement = el;
  }

  @HostListener("keypress", ["$event"])
  onKeyPress(event) {
    if (this.inputElement.nativeElement.value.length < 3) {
      console.log(this.inputElement.nativeElement.value.length + " < 3");
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      console.log(">= 3");
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to interrupt the valueChanges stuff if the input is shorter then 3 char?

p.s. I don't want to put a condition in every operator inside .pipe.

Comment: I mean, you could just put a condition in one operator. `.pipe(filter(value => value.lenght > 4))`

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Comment: sorry I am a dumb !